# Convert meshgrid points into adjacency matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, adjacency-matrix

I am converting mesh-grid points (2D Maze) into Adjacency matrix which I will use later to find the shortest path between the given coordinates. Please have a look into my code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib #for matrices

def cutblocks(xv,yv,allBlocks):
    x_new,y_new = np.copy(xv), np.copy(yv)
    ori_x,ori_y = xv[0][0], yv[0][0]
    for block in allBlocks:
        block = sorted(block)
        block_xmin = np.min((block[0][0], block[2][0]))
        block_xmax = np.max((block[0][0], block[2][0]))
        block_ymin = np.min((block[0][1], block[1][1]))
        block_ymax = np.max((block[0][1], block[1][1]))

        rx_min, rx_max = int((block_xmin-ori_x)/stepSize)+1, int((block_xmax-ori_x)/stepSize)+1
        ry_min, ry_max = int((block_ymin-ori_y)/stepSize)+1, int((block_ymax-ori_y)/stepSize)+1

        for i in range(rx_min,rx_max):
            for j in range(ry_min,ry_max):
                x_new[j][i] = np.nan
        for i in range(ry_min,ry_max):
            for j in range(rx_min,rx_max):
                y_new[i][j] = np.nan
    return x_new, y_new

stepSize = 0.2
##Blocks that should be disabled
allBlocks = [[(139.6, 93.6), (143.6, 93.6), (143.6, 97.6), (139.6, 97.6)],
 [(154.2, 93.4), (158.2, 93.4), (158.2, 97.4), (154.2, 97.4)],
 [(139.2, 77.8), (143.2, 77.8), (143.2, 81.8), (139.2, 81.8)],
 [(154.2, 77.8), (158.2, 77.8), (158.2, 81.8), (154.2, 81.8)],
 [(139.79999999999998, 86.4),
  (142.6, 86.4),
  (142.6, 88.0),
  (139.79999999999998, 88.0)],
 [(154.79999999999998, 87.2),
  (157.6, 87.2),
  (157.6, 88.8),
  (154.79999999999998, 88.8)]]

x = np.arange(136.0, 161.0, stepSize)
y = np.arange(75.0, 101.0, stepSize)

xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
xv, yv = cutblocks(xv,yv,allBlocks)

MazeSize = xv.shape[0]*xv.shape[1]
adj = np.matlib.zeros((MazeSize,MazeSize)) #initialize AdjacencyMatrix

#make 1 whenever there is a connection between neighboring coordinates
mazeR, mazeC = 0,0
for row in range(xv.shape[0]):

    for col in range(xv.shape[1]):
        if xv[row][col]>0 and col+1<xv.shape[1] and round(np.abs(xv[row][col] - xv[row][col+1]),2) == stepSize:
            adj[mazeR,mazeC+1] = 1
            break
        mazeC = mazeC+1
    mazeR = mazeR+1
```

This code generates a mesh-grid in which some of the points are disabled because they are walls in the maze. The cost for every step (between connected vertices) is 1. My questions are: 
1) The adjacency Matrix would be N.N and N=x.y (. is multiply). is that correct?

2) What could be the efficient way of finding and assigning the neighbors to values 1 in the adjacency matrix. ( I tried it but it doesn't work correctly)

3) Should I use graphs for this kind of problems ? My final goal is find the shortest path between the 2 coordinates (vertices).

Thanks

Comment: Yes you should use graphs. I would create a `Node` class that holds a list of Nodes that it is adjacent to. When you traverse, you can say at each given node, attempt to travel to adjacent nodes (depending on your algorithm). If you want shortest path, use Dijkstra's algorithm or A* search.

Comment: You do not need to encode the weight anywhere because the final distance is just equal to the length of the path

Comment: Thank you!
could you please recommend any good library for that ?
Additionally, I have studies little bit about graphs and I am confused how I will assign names for graph nodes (typically ppl assign alphabetical names and I will have many nodes in the maze) ?. Sorry I am not experienced in graph problems.

Comment: Usually those names are just for visualization. Are you familiar with classes and objects in python (or just object oriented programming in general)? I would look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html first, and then maybe start exploring graphical approaches. Good things to try before more advanced approaches would be Breadth first and depth first search, which I would suggest looking up python implementations for and trying to understand them

Comment: There are graphing libraries, but if you are trying to learn I would try to implement them yourself (I think some of the graph libraries are harder to use than just doing it yourself anyways, especially for simpler cases such as this)